# Local HTTP traffic slow on particular Wi-Fi

Tags: macos

I'm facing the effect that local network traffic (against local running Docker containers) is far slower when connected to home Wi-Fi than on my work Wi-Fi.

Making a particular HTTP request against local services takes about 1 second on work Wi-Fi while it takes up to 6 seconds on home Wi-Fi.

**Update**: Disabling IPv6 for Wi-Fi using `networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi` seems to solve the problem.
Is there a way to keep IPv6 enabled and have fast local traffic anyway?

Comment: seems some kind of routing trouble. Are the local IP assignments the same between the two networks [home vs work]. Try comparing the routing table between both networks using `netstat -nr` and check the column `netif` for the destination adapter for each of them that points to the HTTP address range. this is the starting point to look for the cause of that issue.

Comment: I think I found a hint to the cause and I updated the question.

Comment: What about doing the opposite? Disabling ipv6 on Docker? Do you need it for the local Docker containers? This way you could keep it enabled on wifi. Can it be done? (i am a network specialist, but I don't know anything about Docker) Just a suggestion.

Comment: Will try once I find out how https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367837/disable-ipv6-for-docker-on-macos