# Disable IPv6 for Docker on macOS

Tags: macos, docker

How can I disable IPv6 for Docker on macOS?

Comment: Can you explain why you would want to do that?  This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I need to find the root cause of this issue: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367714/local-http-traffic-slow-on-particular-wi-fi

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/):

> IPv6 networking is only supported on Docker daemons running on Linux hosts.

So logically, there is no IPv6 to disable on Docker for Mac.